# Deploying a third party library in perforce

Tags: perforce

I'm working on a third party integration of some technology into an existing product. Currently I'm contracted to the existing product owners to do this, but we both want to make it clear that my work us an addition to the product. I have access to their perforce server, where a binary deployment of my project lives, but the source code for my work lives in another perforce repository. The client doesn't want to mark my folder as writable on their server, but I regularly update the binary files for local testing. Is there some way I can tell perforce to ignore the directory of my product in the clients repositor, without changing it for everyone on th project?

Comment: This needs clarification -- do you mean you want to keep your changes only in your workspace?  Only in your own repository (where the source is)?  Or you want your changes to be in the client's repository but you don't want them to immediately affect other people using that repository?  Where exactly do you want your changes to be and where exactly do you want them not to be?

Comment: I want to work in my own workspace, on my server. I want to transparently be able to deploy my binaries (which are the only things in the client repository) without checking everything out, as by their policy all binaries in my clients perforce are exclusive checkout. I want interfere as little with the clients repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the client create a branch of their binaries that's just for your use.  They should either make this branch writable by you, or set up some other system whereby they'll "drop" your changes there.

When they're ready to accept your changes, they simply copy them from your branch to their "live" version that everyone else uses.